# How do I prevent access on the web to a txt file on my server? i want it to still work, as its for a wizard. But i dont want people to access my code

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I'm wondering if anyone can help me please. I have some text files on my server, which run with a Wizard. The issue I am having is that I'm unable to hide the text files on the web browser.

I've managed to hide the other folders needed, but these are compressed folders. I have worked really hard on coding these txt files, and with the current configuration anyone can just copy them. I don't want them to be accessible at all via web browser but I still need the Text files to work, as they are required for my Wizard. Is it possible, to have it show "403 Access Denied" but the text file still work with my Wizard? The txt files are currently in my html/builds folder.

I've been stuck on this for days, and can't seem to get an answer. I've even opened a support ticket with my host, but they keep showing me how to password protect it, and when I try that option the text files no longer work on my wizard.

My .htaccess currently has the following code in the html folder:

Options +Indexes

```
IndexIgnore /Addontexts
IndexIgnore /builds
IndexIgnore /apktexts
IndexIgnore /insomniacsglobalbuild.zip
IndexIgnore /insomniacspluhbuild.zip
IndexIgnore /insomniacsminigreenbuild.zip
IndexIgnore /apks
IndexIgnore /themedbuilds
IndexIgnore /apkz
IndexIgnore /Advanced.txt
IndexIgnore /addons.txt
IndexIgnore /apk.txt
IndexIgnore /autobuilds.txt
IndexIgnore /notify.txt
IndexIgnore /theme.txt
IndexIgnore /youtube.txt
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Change the permissions or move it outside the document root.

Comment: The wizard is accessing those txt files via backend code or frontend requests (ajax)?

Answer (score 2):

> they keep showing me how to password protect it, and when i try that route, the text files no longer work on my wizard.

That implies that the client needs to be able to access the .txt files for your wizard to work. Given this, it's absolutely, 100% impossible to stop users from being able to read them too. It would be equivalent to DRM, and a lot of companies have spent a lot of money on DRM, all of which has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Any download can be intercepted, and eventually any contents decrypted.

Solutions to this are generally not technical. Put a well defined software license on your work. That way, you can make a case against anyone not respecting your copyright.